# Are those dent corn seeds or sweet corn seeds?

Tags: identification, seeds, corn

I need to know what type of corn seeds these are[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

You should add a picture of the "crown", or top, of the kernels. Dent corn can often (...not always) be identified by the characteristic small indentation ("dent") at the crown of each kernel.

It is hard to see in your pictures, but it looks like there is a very defined "dent" visible, therefore those are very likely dent corn kernels.

Comment: They do have that dent on them, but I saw pictures online that sweet corn seeds have that dent also

Comment: Sweet corn is usually a lot more wrinkly and shriveled when it's dry. But it's very hard to be confident of the variety of corn from the seeds.